# Track cause/location of Application_ThreadException

Tags: c#

I have an application that randomly throws exceptions.
It is proberly a concurrency problem, but i don't quite know where to start the journey.

I cannot make it happen in test enviroment, and I would like some help on extending my exception logging so i can find the excact lines that causes the problem and start finding the cause.

I appriciate any and all proposals

I get this exception and stacktrace

```
ex.message = Object is currently in use elsewhere.
Exception caught at: WndProcException() ==> OnThreadException() ==> Application_ThreadException(sender, ete)
ex. stackTrace:    at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.RenderInternal(HandleRef refTargetDC, BufferedGraphics buffer)
at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.Render()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

It seems to be a button control that is being used/removed while accessed, so i  have been looking at all my button usages

Paint functions used to paint on buttons
readonly static Font LagerFont_B = new Font("Verdana", 8F, FontStyle.Bold);

```
    public static void B_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Button b = sender as Button;
            int p = (int)b.Tag;
            Paint_Red_corner(e, p);

            if (!DataStore.System.Lager_Status_Enable || b.Tag == null)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Enabled = true;
                return;
            }



            if (!DataStore.DATA__Produkter_dic.ContainsKey(p) || !DataStore.DATA__Produkter_dic[p].p.Lager.Lagerstyring_Aktiv)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Enabled = true;
                return;
            }



            decimal l = DataStore.DATA__Produkter_dic[p].p.Lager.Antal_på_Lager;
            if (l == decimal.MinValue)
            {
                ((Button)sender).Enabled = true;
                return;
            }

            if (l < 1)
            {
                const int border = 20;
                ((Button)sender).Enabled = false;
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), border, border, b.Width - border, b.Height - border);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 3), b.Width - border, border, border, b.Height - border);
            }
            else
            {
                ((Button)sender).Enabled = true;
                e.Graphics.DrawString(l.ToString("F0"), LagerFont_B, Brushes.Black, new PointF(5, 5));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void Paint_Red_corner(PaintEventArgs e, int p)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!DataStore.Is_Segment(segment.SUNSET) && DataStore.Kort.Kampagner.Kampagner_eksisterer)
            {
                if (DataStore.Kort.Kampagner.Findes_Produkt_til_Udlevering(p))
                {
                    Point[] points0 = { new Point(0, 0), new Point(0, 25), new Point(25, 0) };
                    Point[] points1 = { new Point(2, 2), new Point(2, 20), new Point(20, 2) };
                    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Black, points0);
                    e.Graphics.FillPolygon(Brushes.Red, points1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are your drowing something by yourself? If so show us your code.

Comment: I have added the paint code in the main question now

Comment: It is a threading bug, an extremely unhealthy one.  Painting must only ever occur on the program's main thread.  The stack trace is normal but what you can't see is that another thread is also busy painting.  Odds to see this crash while testing is very low, if you ever noticed the program deadlocking then that's also caused by this bug.  Hard to set a breakpoint, this occurs in framework code.  A code review is warranted, look at the places where you start a thread.

Comment: Could it be an event raised from another thread, that invalidates the form to force update of custom painting ?